# How can I get a list of XML nodes by value using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to get a XmlNodeList from an XmlDocument for nodes that have a certain value, with a view to removing those nodes.

XML:

```
<List xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/v1">
  <Category>2144</Category>
  <Title>My Object</Title>
  <StartPrice>30.00</StartPrice>
  <ReservePrice>-999</ReservePrice>
  <BuyNowPrice>-999</BuyNowPrice>
</List>
```

Preferably I don't want to iterate through every node and check its value. I looked at trying to use LINQ from some examples but I just don't understand it enough to even attempt it.

I feel I'm getting close-ish with XPath (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) but I'm beginning to think what I want to do isn't supported.

```
string xml = UtilityClass.SerializeObject<Listing> ( myListing);
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument ();
xmlDocument.LoadXml ( xml );
XmlElement root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes ( "//*['-999']" );
```

Am open to other suggestions to get the same result, i.e. remove the nodes with -999 from the Xml document.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to XML is preferred API while dealing with XML in .Net Framework since 2007.

Check it out how easy to achieve what you need in one single statement.

LINQ methods are chained one after another and self-explanatory:

1. Get all descendants of the root node, taking into account a default namespace.
2. Whatever the names of the elements.
3. Where element value is -999.
4. Convert them to a `List<>`.
5. Remove those elements from the XML document.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<List xmlns='http://mynamespace.com/v1'>
          <Category>2144</Category>
          <Title>My Object</Title>
          <StartPrice>30.00</StartPrice>
          <ReservePrice>-999</ReservePrice>
          <BuyNowPrice>-999</BuyNowPrice>
        </List>");

    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    xdoc.Descendants(ns + "List")
        .Elements()
        .Where(x => x.Value.Equals("-999"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Remove());

    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
}
```

**Output**

```
<List xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/v1">
  <Category>2144</Category>
  <Title>My Object</Title>
  <StartPrice>30.00</StartPrice>
</List>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yitzhak Khabinsky, this worked a treat! I did have some problems with double quotes in the original XML and had to add `.Replace ( "\"", "\'" )` to convert them to single quotes. 5 thumbs up for your clear answer, and +1 for a simple explanation of LINQ. :-)